# Beautiful soup find_all p not working wiki parser

Tags: python

using someones wikipedia parser that i shaw I am trying to grab the next element of a p tag for the page history on wikipedia.

```
import sys
import urllib
import urllib2
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
article = sys.argv[1]
while article!="Philosophy" and count<MAX_HOPS:
     articleURL = urllib.quote(article)
     #print "Article URL: %s" %(articleURL)
     opener = urllib2.build_opener()
     opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
     resource = opener.open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + articleURL)
     data = resource.read()
     resource.close()
     soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
     articleTemp = ""
     #('div',id="bodyContent").find_all('p')
     for soupContent in soup.find_all('p')
```

I'm getting a syntax error when I call `find_all('p')` on soup however

```
soupContent = soup.find('div',id="bodyContent").p
```

gives me the first paragraph the problem is I need it to also go through to the second paragraph.

Comment: is this what your code actually looks like? Why does your for loop have no colon(':') or statements within it?

Comment: If I remove the `while` loop (as I don't think `count` or `MAX_HOPS` are defined in the code above) and unindent that section and print `soupContent` in the `for` loop then it works fine for me. Is your syntax error just that you haven't got a proper `for` loop as Totem says?

Answer (score 0):

As Totem suggests above, the `for` loop in your code is not properly formed. I don't see any issue with the `find_all` method itself. For example, the code below runs fine for me:

```
import sys
import urllib
import urllib2
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
article = "Stack_Overflow_(website)"

articleURL = urllib.quote(article)
#print "Article URL: %s" %(articleURL)
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
resource = opener.open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + articleURL)
data = resource.read()
resource.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
articleTemp = ""
#('div',id="bodyContent").find_all('p')
for soupContent in soup.find_all('p'):
     print soupContent.text
```